# What is the difference between Kappa architecture and simply using the stream processing?

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, apache-flink, apache-storm, stream-processing

I would like to ask you one simple question. When I use the Kappa Big Data architecture, it looks like this:

[image]

BUT for me, it looks totally the same as if I was using just some stream processing tool and saving the processed results into some database. So how is it different, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Kappa architecture is composed of two layers: stream processing and serving. The stream processing layer runs the stream processing jobs. Normally, the serving layer is used to query the results.

As I understand you are doing real time message processing as well as storing the result in the database for further queries on incoming data.

In Lambda architecture, serving layer is responsible for querying both batch and speed(aka streaming layers). But in kappa there is no batch layer query. only queries from streaming(speed) layer will be served.

If so, Yes you are on Kappa.

> What is the difference between Kappa architecture and simply using the
>   stream processing?

Speed layer + Serving layer = Kappa architecture (In your case )

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So is there some case, in which I would do a classic stream processing but not doing Kappa architecture?

Comment: may be kafka word count :-) just caliculate result

Comment: but each time I store the processed data in a DB which is queried, it's basically Kappa, right?

Comment: yes... but there are some requirements where you will read from  one kafka topic process it  and publish in to another kafka topic. thats classic example of simple stream processing with out query.

Comment: basically kappa supports query on raw/received data from the streaming application but lambda supports query on both batch and streaming layers.

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram Kappa architecture use one processing layer (no separation to Speed & Batch) but still may require Serving layer to query two representations: historical & latest. You may want to store latest X hours/days/weeks and 2016 results at different databases.